# Lucene neo4j sort with boolean fields

Tags: sorting, lucene, neo4j

I have indexed some documents (nodes of neo4j) with a boolean property which not always is present.
Eg.
Node1

> label : "label A"

Node2:

> label : "label A" (note, same label of node1)
>   special : true

The goal is to get Node2 higher than node 1 for query "label A".

Here the code:

```
Index<Node> fulltextLucene = graphDb.index().forNodes( "my-index" );
Sort sort = new Sort(new SortField[] {SortField.FIELD_SCORE,
                     new SortField("special", SortField.????, true) }); 
IndexHits<Node> results = fulltextLucene.query( "label", new QueryContext( "label A").sort(sort));
```

How can I accomplish that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

are you sure about indexing a property which has only 2 possible values (true, false)?
because indexing means creating a unique value by which you know the position in the database. this unique value depends on the value of the property.

when you have many properties with the same values, the index creates so called collisions - simply, it has several results for an index query. when you are traversing the graph sequentially (without an index), you also have several results which you must choose from. thus, having an index on many nodes with just 2 property values could be worthless.

i suggest create 1 node with this priority value and make relationships to it whenever you need to prioritize a node.

Comment: Makes sense, problem is I get the nodes only by quering lucene and not traversing neo and I don't know how to sort nodes according nodes properties when using lucene.

Comment: unfortunately, i'm not skilled with the REST api. but in pure cypher, it would look like this:  cypher 1.8 start n=node:my-index('label:label A')  with n,n.special as spc return n order by spc [desc];

Comment: With cypher makes sense too, problem is I'm using lucene within neo. I'm implement a suggest feature with wildcard lucene query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort a boolean value like this, you could just use string sorting: SortField.STRING.

This will alfabetically sort the value, so false first, then true. No values (null) come for false.